# Join query using DB facade in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have write a join query using DB Facade in laravel. but when i'm run it, it don't show any error or any data just show an empty array.
Here is my code.

```
public function memberdetails($id)
{

   $user = DB::table('userinformations')
        ->join('users', 'userinformations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('userinformations.*','users.*')
        ->where('userinformations.user_id','=',$id)
        ->get();
    return $user;
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try `print_r(memberdetails($id));`? Do You get nothing, just an empty string, or false? Maybe an empty array?

Comment: it's show the id, but when print user it's show empty array

Comment: Then you don't have any results maching your query.

Comment: @Gabrielle did you check the record with $id is present in both tables ?

Comment: Either you have `no data matched` or wrong value for `$id`

Comment: The code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check your both table then try this.
use DB facade.

```
$user = DB::table('userinformations')
    ->join('users', 'userinformations.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->select('userinformations.*','users.*')
    ->where('userinformations.user_id','=',$id)
    ->get();
return $user;
```